# install laravel homestead error

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, homestead

I am trying to install laravel homestead. I follow the steps on the site, but when i am at the step where i have to do:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I have windows and i use git bash. He downloads a while and then i get this error message(this is the all the text when i download(maybe it is helpfull for you). The error is at the bottom):

```
$ vagrant box add --insecure laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) parallels
2) virtualbox
3) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 2
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
```

I read maybe it works when i did: vagrant box add laravel/homestead -c, but dont works for me. And i tried this: http://slick.pl/kb/software/vagrant-fix-for-error-60-ssl-read/. This also dont work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/401 is it the https as shown in this issue

Comment: Thanks. Do you know in which folder i have to be? I am now in: ~/.vagrant.d/tmp

Comment: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

Comment: Sorry its not formatted it very well... on that command use http instead of https

Comment: or another user has put `vagrant box add --insecure -c laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

Comment: Thanks i gonna try this. But if i start my terminal can i do this direct or do i need to get in a specific folder?

Comment: I believe you can do it from anywhere. Let me know how it goes and I'll add this as an answer if successful. Thanks

Comment: Yes i do that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks man it works

Comment: Yes!! Excellent news. I've added it as the answer if you could accept it. Thanks. Add a comment to which was the one you did.

Comment: if i go further with the steps from laravel i do this: init.bat. i get the error bash: init.bat: command not found. Do you also know how to fix this?

Comment: have you cd into Homestead?

Comment: Here is a tutorial that may help [Example](http://robert-askam.co.uk/posts/post/installing-homestead-and-laravel-5)

Comment: Yes I am in Homestead

Comment: I do it exactly like that tutorial

Comment: If you go to the homestead folder can you see a init.bat file?

Comment: Yes there are two

Comment: You can just double click and run it manually. Not sure why there are two though, you might need to investigate. But try running it manually and it should allow you to continue your setup.

Comment: Thanks it works. So now i just go further with the steps on laravel?

Comment: Yep. Keep following it now. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: By everything i do i still get the errer: command not found

Comment: You can skip the init.bat now and move onto the section configuring Homestead in the Laravel instructions.

Comment: Yes, if i typ provider: virtualbox. I get the error command not found. By everything what i do i get this. If I do ls I get: bash: ls: command not found.

Comment: Ok, take a second to read the docs. You should now be editing the yaml file inside your Homestead. Not sure why your bash isn’t working. Sounds like you have changed some settings. Have a google.

Comment: Yes I already fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what was discussed in the comments to fix this. Issue is here
[Github Isuue](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/401)

Here is the general consensus though, replace the https to http as below

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

OR

```
vagrant box add --insecure -c laravel/homestead http://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

Comment: tried the first one, and yeah it works. you're an awesome human being XD